# Copy json blob to ADX table

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have an ADF with a copy activity which copies a json blob to kusto.

I have did the following:

1. Created a json mapping in the kusto table.
2. In the "Sink" section of the copy activity: I set the Ingestion mapping name field the name of #1.
3. In the mapping section of the copy activity, I mapped all the fields.

When I run the copy activity, I get the following error:

"**Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorKustoWriteFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failure status of the first blob that failed: Mapping reference wasn't found.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.KustoConnector,'**"

I looked in kusto for ingestion failures and I see this:
**Mapping reference 'mapping1' of type 'mappingReference' in database '' could not be found.**

Why am I seeing those errors even though I have an ingestion mapping on the table and what do I need to do to correct it?

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the ingestion format specified in the ADF is not json.

Comment: I don't see a place in the ADF copy activity sink that defines the format.

Comment: If you do not see it, it means that it is a CSV, this is why it worked when you removed the mapping since CSV has default mapping (i.e. mapping is optional).

Comment: The blob itself is json format so it made sense to me to add a json mapping in kusto. Is CSV default in ADF "copy to kusto" even though the blob data is json?

Comment: Yes, ADF does the transformation to CSV from json, see section (2) in the walkthrough here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-load-data

Answer (score 0):

Well, After I removed the **mapping** name in the sink section, it works.

Looks like the docs are not updated because it states that you can define both:

"ingestionMappingName   Name of a pre-created mapping on a Kusto table. To map the columns from source to Azure Data Explorer (which applies to all supported source stores and formats, including CSV/JSON/Avro formats), you can use the copy activity column mapping (implicitly by name or explicitly as configured) and/or Azure Data Explorer mappings."